# Poisson process, independence and order statistics

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Let $(N_t)$ be a standard Poisson process. By construction we know that if $(T_i)$ are the jump times then $T_{i+1}-T_i$ are independent and identically distributed exponential random variables. It is also well know that conditionally on the set $\{N_1 = n\}$ (after a unit of time the process had $n$ jumps) then the jump times $(T_i)$ are distributed as the order statistic $(U_{(i)})$ of $n$ independent and uniform random variables.

My question: Is it true that the differences $U_{(i)}-U_{(i-1)}$ are also i.i.d.?

I think is not to hard to probe that they have the same distribution but i don't know if is it true that they are independent.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Of course not, if one of them is very large, say greater than $.9999$, this provides a huge information on all the others, don't you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Corrected to include the last difference.) The differences are *exchangeable*: Define $V_i:=U_{(i)}-U_{(i-1)}$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ ($U_{(0)}:=0$) and  $V_{n+1}:=1-U_{(n)}$, and let $\sigma$ be any permutation of $\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}$. Then $(V_{\sigma(1)},V_{\sigma(2)},\ldots,V_{\sigma(n+1)})$ has the same distribution as $(V_1,V_2,\ldots,V_{n+1})$.

Comment: Thanks. Is it posible to derive a joint distribution of  $(V_i)_{i=1,\dots,n}$?